# Android Studio is showing wrong project name

Tags: android-studio

I have an Android Studio Project , the original name was **GUI-refresh-by-time** however it is showing **Typer** in the main screen.

[image]

But when I open the project, it becomes **GUI-refresh-by-time**

[image]

My `.idea/.name` is called **"GUI-refresh-by-time"**

How can I resolve this issue? It might lead confusion specially when you have too many projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solve it anyway.

> The problem occurs because I have another Android Studio project name
>   **Typer** , both of them are located in the same Folder Location **root/Gui-GUI-refresh-by-time** and **root/Typer**

Basically this **root/Typer** does not have **.idea/.name** so I decided to delete the Typer project Folder and reopen my Android Studio, after then it works.

Answer (score 1):

you could just remove the project from the workplace by saving it elsewhere and try reimporting it